# wordpress losing the session on page refresh

Tags: php, ajax, session, wordpress

I'm trying to develop a plugin for the wordpress and i'm having a small issue with the session. I have created my own login page for my plugin and when user puts his username/password and press the login button an ajax request sends the data to a function to check if user details are correct or not. The function that the ajax is calling is stored inside my index.php of my plugin. Using the $_SESSION in the function that ajax is calling, i can print the variable that I want,which has been set inside another file. Then if the data are correct the ajax reloads the page. When the page is been reloaded the session no more exist. Does anyone knows how i can solve this problem? I implemented the plugin on a localserver which was working fine, but when i uploaded the project on a subdomain on a server, it stopped to working.

AJAX code

```
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        if (data !='')
        {
            var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
            if (obj.status == "ok")
            {
                location.reload();
            }
        }
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the .RememberState function with your ajax call? Typically this might be applied to a form (so if the form is partially filled out and a user refreshes the page their changes are preserved), but in theory I don't see why you couldnt use it on the document itself. Check out this link it might explain it more clearly

http://shaneriley.com/jquery/remember_state/

You'd want to do this before the call, and in the success callback, you should be able to use this RememberState to return to the active session you had before. If this isn't what you're referring to I apologize for misinterpreting your question.

Comment: the Session is been set when on the function that the AJAX call and not before the call of the AJAX

Comment: are you doing something with the success callback of the ajax call? That would be where you would need to re-instantiate the session if you're confident that it's being set

Comment: So is the $_SESSION being stored in the data that gets returned from the ajax call? Because location.reload() isn't taking any arguments so I don't think it will know what the $_SESSION was. At least that's how i'm interpreting it

Comment: basically the ajax calls a function called A, which is inside the index.php. then this function requires another file which contains the login function passing the user and pass of the user. if the data are correct then the login function creates the sessions and returns back to the A function true or false based on the results. then the A function returns a json_encoded result back to the ajax